# Delete records in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to delete records of a row after clicking in delete button where I am using AJAX, I tried the following but it is giving me an error:

```
//index.php
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
  var Serial = $(this).attr("Serial"); 
  if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this data?")) 
  {
   var action = "Delete"; 
   $.ajax({
    url:"plans-action.php?square=$selsquare",    
    method:"POST",     
    data:{Serial:Serial, action:action}, 
    success:function(data)
    {
     fetchUser();    
     alert(data);   
    }
   })
  }
  else  
  {
   return false;
  }
 });
});

//plans-fetch.php
```

here is what i did in the server side php code

```
if(isset($_POST["action"])) 
{

if($_POST["action"] == "Delete")
 {
  $statement = $connection->prepare(
   "DELETE FROM plans WHERE SquareNo = '$selsquare' AND Serial = :Serial"
  );
  $result = $statement->execute(
   array(
    ':Serial' => $_POST["Serial"]
   )
  );
  if(!empty($result))
  {
   echo 'Data Deleted';
  }
 }


}
```

Comment: can you tell us your error?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Also you need to fetch the $selsquare from $_GET to pass in query

Comment: @AgamBanga he's using `$_POST`

Comment: Ohhh, I thought he is passing some variable in this piece of code
`url:"plans-action.php?square=$selsquare",  `. This is so confusing using this type of name

Comment: I am passing a variable $selsquare

Comment: @martinBibo why are you passing that variable? instead of including it with the data you are passing to `PHP`.

Comment: If you are passing, you need to get in the php file also with $_GET

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to append the parameters to the end of url as you are using `POST`. Include the parameters in the data section of the `$.post` function. It is recommended to use `data-` when using custom attributes, your Serial attribute should be something like `data-serial="somevalue"` instead of `Serial="somevalue"`

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    // using data-serial 
    // var serial = $(this).data('serial');
    var serial = $(this).attr("Serial");
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this data?"))
    {
        var action = "Delete";
        var selsquare = <?php echo $selsquare; ?>; // echo value from php
        $.ajax({
            url:"plans-action.php", //  url:"plans-action.php?square=$selsquare" we don't need params
            method:"POST",
            data:{Serial:serial, action: action, selsquare: selsquare },
            success:function(data)
            {
                fetchUser();
                alert(data);
            }
        })
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Then in your `PHP`

```
if (isset($_POST["action"])) {

    if ($_POST["action"] == "Delete") {
        $selsquare = $_POST['selsquare'];
        $statement = $connection->prepare("DELETE FROM plans WHERE SquareNo = '$selsquare' AND Serial = :Serial");
        $result = $statement->execute(array(':Serial' => $_POST["Serial"]));
        if (!empty($result)) {
            echo 'Data Deleted';
        }
    }

}
```